# grepWin: Find this but not that (search for a page that has a string but not another)

Tags: regex, search, find, full-text-search

I am trying to find **files** that have a certain word *but at the same time* missing another (in any order) through grepWin for Win 10 (v. 2.0.13).  I tried with both options "Dot match newline" and without, but still it shows wrong results (please find example file contents at the end of the question).

I tried many regex, but they work for same line only (in np++), not whole files.

`^(?!.*not).*yes.*$` → this finds files (1), (3), (4)

`(?=.*yes)(?!.*not)(.+)`  → this finds files (1), (3), (4)

`^(?!.[\s\S]*not).[\s\S]*yes.*$` → this finds files (1), (4)

What I need is to find files that has a certain word (ex: yes), and not the other (ex: not). So if the file has both words it doesn't show in the results (something like a 2-step inverse search), it shows only the file that has the main word, and if the other word is present, it doesn't show it in the search results.

---

Let's say that we have 4 text files, **(1)** one has the word `yes` only, **(2)** another has `not` only, **(3)** third has both with `yes` first, **(4)** and fourth with both with `not` first.

I want to find only the file that has only `yes` [file number (1) which is yes.txt in the following example].

Here are the four files:

**(1) yes.txt**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. only yes Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

---

**(2) not.txt**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor only not incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

---

**(3) both-a.txt**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute yes irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor not incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

---

**(4) both-b.txt**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute not irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor yes incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: Does It have to be in `grepWin` only or you have `awk`, `grep` etc available as well?

Comment: Thanks for reply, not sure what's that.  I am using grepWin v. 2.0.13 on Win 10

Comment: What about `(?![\s\S]*not)[\s\S]*yes` ?

Comment: Thanks @trincot, this gives results of file that has `yes` AND file that has `both` (with yes last).  The point is that the words are in any place or any line in the file,, not the same.  Also the words (yes, not) could be in any order, this first, or that first.

Comment: I have added example files of which file I want to find (which is file **(1)** only). Thanks.

Comment: So `^(?![\s\S]*not)[\s\S]*yes` does it?

Comment: No, it finds file **(1)** *and* file **(4)**.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce that](https://regex101.com/r/2KcmgU/1): doesn't match file (4).

Comment: idk why grepWin shows both!

Comment: Also in Notepad++ when I search for this `^(?![\s\S]*not)[\s\S]*yes` in file (4) it finds a line that has `yes`, although there is a `not` in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex works for me (assuming they should be in fact words as your attempt regexes didn't consider that at all):

```
\A(?!.*\bnot\b).*\byes\b
```

Explantation:

- `\A` - matches the start of the whole string (note that normally grepWin matches in multiline mode, so `^` didn't work well to not match `not`)
- `(?!.*\bnot\b)` - negative lookahead to get rid of possible `not` matches preceded by anything. `\b` are used to mark it as word
- `.*\byes\b` - similar case to above, except it just matches `yes` normally

Ofc it should be used with "dot matches newline" option.